# Finding SQL Schema for Product Pricings with Separate Vendor Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema

I'm struggling to find a good schema for my current task, and would greatly appreciate a little input.

I'm working with a very large project that includes the tables `Products`, `ProductPricings` and `Vendors`. (The definitions below were reworked to be more concise.)

**Products**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductsId]       [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Comments]         [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProductsId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**ProductPricing**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductPricing](
    [ProductPricingId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductsId]       [int] NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate]    [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [BasePrice]        [money] NOT NULL,
    [BaseCost]         [money] NOT NULL,
    [PriceTaxRate]     [decimal](10, 6) NOT NULL,
    [CostTaxRate]      [decimal](10, 6) NOT NULL,
    [GratuityRate]     [decimal](10, 6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT         [PK_ProductPricing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ProductPricingId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Vendors**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vendors](
    [VendorsId]        [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description]      [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion]       [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT         [PK_Vendors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [VendorsId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A Product can include any number of ProductPricings.

**My Tasks:**

1. Associate each ProductPricing with a Vendor.
2. Allow the user to specify an order of Vendors within each Product. (Determines which one has higher priority.)

**My Proposed Changes:**

I'm looking at adding a new table, `ProductVendors`. And then adding an FK from ProductPricings to ProductVendors.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductVendors](
    [ProductVendorsId] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductsId]       INT      NOT NULL,
    [VendorsId]      INT      NOT NULL,
    [SortOrder]        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductVendors_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductsId] ASC, [CompaniesId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductVendors_Products] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductsId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProductPricing] ([ProductsId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductVendors_Vendors] FOREIGN KEY ([VendorsId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Vendors] ([VendorsId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This approach offers the following benefits:

1. Allows me to control the order of Vendors for each Product.
2. Allows me to associated each ProductPricing with a Vendor.

Here's what I dislike about this approach:

1. A ProductPricing is associated with a Product in 2 ways: Via the FK `ProductsId`, and also through the ProductVendors table. This established *two versions of truth*. Hopefully, they would always reference the same Product, but it would be awkward to establish a constraint for this.
2. This approach is more code intensive. When associating a ProductPricing with a Vendor, I must check if the Product already has this ProductVendor, and create it if not. And, when unassociating a ProductPricing with a Vendor, I need to check if any other ProductPricings are associated with that Vendor and, if not, need to delete the orphaned ProductVendors.

I know that's a lot of information. But is there a better way to work this? (If it makes any difference, I'm using C#, ASP.NET, and SQL Server.)

Comment: fyi, for vendors create stmt, got: Cannot use TEXTIMAGE_ON when a table has no text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml or large user defined type columns. on 2005

Comment: Where is CompaniesID (on dbo.ProductVendors) coming from?  Was that the VendorID?

Comment: From your description can you add VendorsID and SortOrder to the ProductPricing table?

Comment: TEXTIMAGE_ON is probably redundant unless there are multiple file groups... it just gets added by SSMS and probably wasn't "simplified" out by the OP?

Comment: @Beth: Sorry, I did some quick editing to make it more concise. I'm more a C# programmer than a database one.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg: Yes, it's called the Companies table in my actual database. Knew I'd miss something. Sorry.

Comment: @SeanLange: No, that won't do it because a Vendor must only have one sort order per Product. This would give Vendors a separate sort order for each ProductPricing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would add the VendorsId to ProductPricing.  That's the first job on your list done.

Next I would add a new table to allow vendor preferences to be stored:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductVendors (
    [ProductVendorsId] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductsId]       INT      NOT NULL,
    [VendorsId]      INT      NOT NULL,
    [PreferenceOrder]        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY etc...
FOREIGN KEY etc...
```

...and that's the second job done.

So to recap, you have a way to associate vendors with product prices and to allow vendor preference to be stored without introducing a loop in your data :D

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate a little why you think this is better? It basically is what I proposed except you have the ProductPricing table reference the Vendors table directly instead of going through the ProudctVendors table, right. There is still some work as far as adding and removing associations between ProductPricing and Vendors (need to manage the list of ProductVendors). But, yes, I see you have eliminated the *two versions of truth issue.*

Comment: As I see it you have two distinct jobs, one to allow a preference order for vendors by product and one to assign product pricings to vendors.  I think the best way to do this is to keep these two changes separate rather than trying to combine them in any way.  There are probably other ways to achieve both aims but usually the simplest solution is the best for database design?

Comment: Yeah, I've taken your advice here but I'm not completely satisfied due to the extra work needed and it's also kind of awkward to group and order the data with this schema. But perhaps there is no simpler approach.

Comment: If the data is difficult to report on then a VIEW might be the way forward?